# "No journal files were found" on chrooted rescue system

Tags: boot, server, ssh, chroot, rescue-mode

I have a remote Ubuntu 16.04 server that I can't reach via ssh after I shut it down and booted it again. I had OpenSSH Server installed during system installation and I never disabled it (e.g. `systemctl disable` or `update-rc.d remove`).

In order to find out the error I rebooted the server in rescue mode (via web interface of the server hoster) and chrooted to the root partition:

```
root@rescue ~ # mount /dev/md2 /mnt
root@rescue ~ # chroot /mnt
```

The filesystem looks fine so far, but there is no boot log (`/var/log/boot` or similar). The syslog ends exactly at the time when I shut down the server, no new entries seem to have been added.

I found out that as per 16.04 I have to use journalctl to get the logs so I tried:

```
root@rescue ~ # journalctl
No journal files were found.
-- No entries --
```

The ssh server might not be the primary problem since I have a rather sophisticated network configuration including routes to a failover ip (the server being a node of a ha-cluster). Some other service could be failing so that ssh server doesn't start up.

Nevertheless I tried to enable ssh on startup:

```
root@rescue ~ # systemctl enable ssh
Synchronizing state of ssh.service with SysV init with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install...
Executing /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable ssh
```

But to no avail, after `shutdown -r now` I still can't reach the server. nmap gives me

```
Host is up (0.037s latency).
Not shown: 996 closed ports
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
135/tcp  filtered msrpc
445/tcp  filtered microsoft-ds
593/tcp  filtered http-rpc-epmap
1720/tcp filtered H.323/Q.931
```

I just can't find a way to figure out what the problem might be. Could anybody give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that I had an error in `/etc/fstab` so nothing could be written to the log files.

Answer (score 0):

I think before

```
chroot /mnt
```

you have to

```
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev &&
sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts &&
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc &&
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
```

Comment: I tried and `mount` shows all the devices mounted properly, but still no entries in journalctl